# 2011 Chevy Malibu ltz gas intake issues with check engine light

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, cel, gasoline, malibu

The Check Engine Light came on and diagnosis came back. It has to do with the gas tank intake, it does not want to take gas when refilling the tank. It takes some then quits. It take 30 minutes or more to fill up and it has a lot of pressure behind the gas cap when taking it off. What causes this and how is it fixed?

Comment: What exactly were the stored codes?  There could be many things wrong here.

Comment: could be a blocked vent hose or failed vent solenoid. iirc the vent valve/hose is not easily accessed on that MY.